# When cancel button of searchBar is clicked, it should remove the keyboard from the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am using a searchBar wherein the cancel button of searchBar when clicked should remove the keyboard. I tried using resignFirstResponder but thats not working at all. Does anyone have any other way out for it?

Comment: Did you tried `resignFirstResponder` in `- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` delegate method of `UISearchBar`?

Comment: Yes i have tried. Still its not working

Comment: Can you show the code in `UISearchBar` delegate methods?

Comment: check my above code in the delegates. Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: check my code it works 1000%

Answer (score 0):

use this line, it will help you

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: bah! beat me to the punch :)

Answer (score 0):

Without any code in OP, try this:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

You'll need one/all of these methods:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: you mean put this line in the shouldEndBegining property of the searchBar right? I tried it there its not working.

Comment: No, you'll need to put it in one of the delegate methods of the `UISearchBar`

Comment: Yes i tried it there also. its not working , the keyboard remains there only.

Answer (score 0):

this test code it work 1000%.

In your .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate>
```

set delegate in your viewDidLoad method

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchBar *searchBar;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.searchBar setDelegate:self];
}
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

    [self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES];
    return YES;
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.text = @"";
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```